# Invisible text is still visible in the overview

Tags: android

Please assist,

I have hidden text in the onPause() however when clicking the square (overview) button as per the image below the text still appears as visible.
I do not want the user to view the text as it could be a way of cheating.

Thanks

My code:

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    sumTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {

        sumTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        super.onPause();
    }
```

[image: When overview button pressed]

Comment: Did you try to call super first then invisible code

Comment: Thanks for input, I did try it now but still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you make set visibilty INVISIBLE for On resume then text will be invisible

OR

Try only this by commenting onResume section and use this
  @Override
    public void onPause() {

```
    sumTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    super.onPause();
}
```

if you had both overriding methods then it will vanish for only a point of time

Comment: https://developer.android.com/images/training/basics/basic-lifecycle-paused.png       See this image when it is onpause it is paritally visible and  there fore you cannot make this invisible when you minimse the application    The  best thing you can do it is make it completely invisble and Make it Visible when we use activity